# DD-WRT to redirect incoming traffic to a home Plex server

Tags: dd-wrt

I am not sure if this is possible, however I have domain with DNS only pointing to my home boarder router. I have setup port forwarding from port 80 to port 32400 of a windows computer running Plex media server.

Currently I have to connect via mydomain.com/web/index.html, I can not change this through Plex, so I was wondering if I can setup my DD-wrt router to redirect mydomain.com connections to mydomain.com/web/index.html?

I have looked into DNSmasq but I think that only works locally. Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` in your `mydomain.com/` to redirect all request to `mydomain.com/web/index.html`

Just add this line to it:

```
Redirect / http://mydomain.com/web/index.html
```

Comment: This may be a silly question but can I do that if I just have a domain with godaddy (DNS only, no hosting)? I thought that .htaccess is an apache thing. Or could I somehow put this file on my router which I guess is some kind of linux server.

Comment: No, you cannot do it if you have no hosting. Where are you files hosted then?

Comment: The videos are hosted on a windows PC, the only problem is that Plex is the web server, and I don't think it is possible to modify how it works.

I was mainly concerned that mydomain.com returns an XML file with all my Plex details that I don't want public. Fortunately requests from outside the network are forbidden. As such whilst it would still be nicer to have a shorter URL, it is not really that important.

Comment: look in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Plex Media Server\